# Why is html canvas animation rendering a temporary gap for each new rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an array of rectangles, or "pipes" that are rendered on html5 canvas. New pipes are dynamically added to an array before being rendered (and animated). The issue is that each new pipe has a tiny gap in between itself and the preceding pipe, this gap disappears once the next pipe is introduced. There should be no gap at any point.

It's so bizarre and it's driving me mad.

The Codepen link below should make this question much clearer.

[Codepen working example.](https://codepen.io/blangdon/pen/VqWVmJ)

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const canvasWidth = 500;
const canvasHeight = 820;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var frame_count = 0;
var speed = 1;
var pipes = [];

function Pipe(height) {
  this.x = canvasWidth;
  this.height = height;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, 0, 100, this.height);
    this.x = this.x - (1 * speed);
  };
}

function setup() {
  // Render blank canvas to dom
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  body.appendChild(canvas);
}

function draw() {
  // Clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Pipe generator
  if (frame_count % 100 === 0) {
    if (frame_count % 200 === 0) {
      pipes.push(new Pipe(100));
    } else {
      pipes.push(new Pipe(120));
    }
  }

  // Draw pipes
  for (i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    pipes[i].update();
  }

}

function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    draw();
    frame_count++;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }, 0);
}

setup();
loop();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because in your drawing function you do everything in reverse ;-)

Currently you are first filling the current path, then declaring it and finally update the position. You need to do it all the other way around, so that you do fill the latest version of your drawings, instead of waiting one frame to do so.

It appeared to get fixed when more than one shape was getting drawn because in the same frame, the next shapes were drawing the current state of the previous shape.

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const canvasWidth = 500;
const canvasHeight = 820;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var frame_count = 0;
var speed = 1;
var pipes = [];

function Pipe(height) {
  this.x = canvasWidth;
  this.height = height;
  this.update = function() {
    // first update position
    this.x = this.x - (1 * speed);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    // then declare the path
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, 0, 100, this.height);
    // finally draw it
    ctx.fill();
  };
}

function setup() {
  // Render blank canvas to dom
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  body.appendChild(canvas);
}

function draw() {
  // Clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Pipe generator
  if (frame_count % 100 === 0) {
    if (frame_count % 200 === 0) {
      pipes.push(new Pipe(100));
    } else {
      pipes.push(new Pipe(120));
    }
  }

  // Draw pipes
  for (i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    pipes[i].update();
  }

}

function loop() {
// do not mix setTimeout and rAF, it's like having a Ferrari parked in a truck...
//  setTimeout(function() {
    draw();
    frame_count++;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
//  }, 0);
}

setup();
loop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the setTimeout note :). I'm new to js (and programming in general) and had pasted this loop function from elsewhere.